# 12 и 16-колоночная система Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, frontend

Мне нужно сверстать адаптивный сайт по макетам из PSD. Но проблема в том что для широких экранов макет сделан с использованием сетки на 16 колонок Bootstrap, для средних на 12, для маленьких на 5. Выходит что при изменении разрешения экрана, должна меняться система сеток. И как при этом писать код, если при разном разрешении он будет разный.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю *путь bootstrap*, надо все три варианта верстать в макете на 16 колонок. Хотя я бы не отходил от стандартных 12-ти колонок и 16 сверстал бы, используя вложенность. Ну или вообще отказаться от bootstrap и разработать свою сетку, но это трудоёмко.

Comment: Возможно несколько вариантов решения данной задачи, от нахождения общего множителя, до написания стилей для собственной колонки. Главное, не забывайте про здравый смысл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще странно, что макет изначально рисуется под бутстрап на 16 колонок. Обычно 12 колонок более, чем достаточно и грамотный веб-дизайнер так не будет поступать. Но всегда есть исключения, истинной причины так поступать не знаю... Поэтому!

**Отвечая на Ваш вопрос:**

Если всё же нужно сохранить 16 колонок и использовать бутстрап - настройте его на 16 колонок [здесь](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/#grid-system) (переменная @grid-columns) для версии 3.4 или [здесь](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid) (переменная $grid-columns) для версии 4.2. Полученный сгенерированный бутстрап (если это версия 3.4) подключите стандартным способом к проекту. В случае с версией 4.2 достаточно просто заменить значение переменной и сохранить.

Для более мелких разрешений, где необходимо использовать 12 и 5 колонок - используйте 1 колонку как 3 (например 3 справа/слева и 10 в середине). Для объединенных 3-х можно использовать внутреннюю микросетку из 16 колонок и т.д.

Для 5 колонок - по аналогии: 3 по цетру (по две) и 1 справа/слева (по пять). Внутри них также микросетка.

[image: Пример сетки на 16/12/5 колонок]

P.S. Вы можете менять соотношения на своё усмотрение, я привёл просто один из вариантов реализации (с микросеткой внутри по 16 колонок).